# Thoughts on this limit ? $\lim_\limits{x\to 3}\dfrac{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{x}}{x-3}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_\limits{x\to 3}\dfrac{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{x}}{x-3}$$

Normally, one multiplies by $\frac{3x}{3x}$ to eliminate the complex fraction.  Here, that will not eliminate the problematic denominator term of $(x-3)$.   Neither will subtracting the numerator via LCD.    Or will it?!  Wait a sec...

Comment: Where is $n$???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{x}}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to3}\frac{\frac{x}{3x}-\frac{3}{3x}}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to3}\frac{\frac{x-3}{3x}}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to3}\frac{x-3}{3x(x-3)}=\lim_{x\to3}\frac{1}{3x}=\frac{1}{3\cdot3}=\frac{1}{9}$$

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean $x$. Notice that $$\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{\frac{x-3}{3x}}{x-3} =\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{1}{3x}=\frac{1}{9}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

We can apply [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) with $f(x)=1/3-1/x$ and $g(x)=x-3$. Then $f^\prime(x)=x^{-2}$ and $g^\prime(x)=1$. Hence,

$$\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{1/3-1/x}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{x^{-2}}{1}=\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{1}{x^2},$$
And now it is easy, the limit is $1/9$.

Comment: Isn't applying L'Hopital *really* circular, given that the limit is already by definition the derivative of $h(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$ at $3$ (and to apply L'Hopital, you need to invoke an actually non-trivial theorem, and... compute the derivative of $-\frac{1}{x}$ in the process)?

Comment: @ClementC. It would depend on the context of the question. If you know the theorem, and you know basic derivatives, L'Hôpital is my preferred way to quickly calculate limits. I do not see that the arguments circular, however, if the "goal" is to find the derivative, L'Hôpital invokes an unnecessary calculation (finding the general form to find the value at $3$).

Comment: The point is: if you know how to compute the derivative, just do it and evaluate it at 3: L'Hopital is not necessary. And if you don't,  then L'Hopital is outside the scope.

Comment: @ClementC. Okay, I see your point now.